# Custom Android view like the one that shows app in menus

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

My app has a lot of similar buttons with an image and title at its bottom. All I want is an easier way to do it so that I dont have to replicate views. Since it gets dirty in xml.

I believe I have to ways.

1) Using the include tag. But in this case how can I change the name of the child image and textview directly in the main screen where I am including this custom view.
2) Build a custom view with on Draw etc. Dont want to try this because it looks quite achievable 
from the last idea.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Buttons for this purpose. Set transparent background to it, your text and your image as drawableTop property.

[Example](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/layout/fragment_dashboard.xml) from Google IO application:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/home_btn_schedule"
    style="@style/DashboardButton"
    android:text="@string/btn_schedule"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/home_btn_schedule" />
```

Styles from this example is [here](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/res/values/styles.xml).

Comment: A very simple solution! Great. It hasnt got anything to do with styles the trick was the drawableTop. Yet still I really would like to master the include thing for other situations. It would be great if you can give me some info on that.

Comment: Can recommend only Romain Guy's article about include tag: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html I don't know other articles :)

Answer (score 0):

i think include will do the job. basically when you include a view and set ids for its child view's you can just simply use findViewById() to get a reference to those views. includes act the same way as if you actually have the full xml. alternatively you can find its parent by id which would be something like LinearLayout lin = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_ref) and then use lin.findViewById(R.id.myIncludedTextView) to get the reference to your view.

also don't forget to vote :D

Comment: But i want to do it through xml. Any solution?